# Complex integral substitution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am trying to solve:

$$ \int^{2 \pi}_{0} e^{cos \theta} cos(\theta -sin(\theta))d\theta $$

I tried to do the following substitution:

$ z = e^{i \theta } \rightarrow \theta =-i ln(z)$

$ dz = i e^{i \theta} d\theta = izd\theta $

$cos\theta = \frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{{2}}$

$sin\theta = \frac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{{2i}}$

and I got:

$$ \int e^{z/2}e^{1/{2z}}cos(-i ln(z)-\frac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{{2i}})dz$$

I dont think this will take me anywhere

Is there a better aproach?

Comment: As long as you have (rather current) expressions of the form $\theta-\sin(\theta)$ or $\theta-\cos(\theta)$, don't waste your time looking for exact formulas... there are not.

Comment: @JeanMarie. In this case, there is ! Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Bonjour ! Yes indeed. My bad ! I though that  it was an indefinite integral (I must have dreamt ; surely the bounds have not been added later)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help you get started, let $$A = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos \theta}\cos(\theta-\sin \theta)\,d\theta,$$ and $$B = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos \theta}\sin(\theta-\sin \theta)\,d\theta.$$

Obviously, both $A$ and $B$ are real numbers. Also, \begin{align}A-iB &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos \theta}[\cos(\theta-\sin \theta)-i\sin(\theta-\sin \theta)]\,d\theta
\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos \theta}e^{-i(\theta-\sin \theta)}\,d\theta
\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos \theta+i\sin\theta}e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta
\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{i\theta}}e^{-i\theta}\,d\theta
\\
&= \oint_{C}\dfrac{e^{z}}{iz^2}\,dz
\end{align}
where $C$ is the curve parameterized by $z = e^{i\theta}$ over $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: But solving the integral will give A-iB, how do I get only A?

Comment: Should I get the real part of the answer?

Comment: ^Yes. Since $A$ and $B$ are real, you can get $A$ by taking the real part of $A-iB$.